# setValue: Not Getting Called for Textfield Before Enabled State Changes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-coding

I've a radio button with 2 options each of which has an associated textfields.  I want to disable the textfield of the radio button that is not selected when the selected button changes.

If I modify the textfield and immediately after select the radio button, the `setValue:` is called only for radio's key path, but not for the textfield's key path.

The change in enabled state overrides the last value in the textfield causing the changed value to be lost.

Here're some snapshots:

Original state

[image]

After modifying:

[image]

After changing the radio button (top textfield is reverted):

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify which textfield, and which radio button, the behavior you're describing applies to?

Comment: Sorry for the unlinked links, but I haven't enough reputation to post the images... :(

Comment: By the way, how did you accomplish the "in" units displaying in the Absolute field? A display pattern?

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem a couple years ago and found a good solution [here](http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/229). Hopefully this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the behavior you're seeing is correct. If the user is disabling a text field in the middle of an editing session, the edits *should* cancel.

If you were using selective disclosure instead of selective enablement, which would mean hiding the text fields which don't apply instead of disabling them, it makes more sense to discard edits to a control that's about to disappear. It's reasonable to apply the same here.

Comment: Well, the same happens with the stepper and the closer textfield. If I change the value and immediately after push step up or down, it'll call setValue with value = old value +/- 1

Answer (score 0):

Setting the text field control to **Continuous** should cause it to `setValue:` after every keypress.